# How to read USB data sent to a dot matrix printer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing, usb

I'm trying to create an interface between a PC and a dot matrix printer to change the printed messages. I've no access to the PC. The printer is connected using an USB cable. I'd like to plug that USB cable to my own computer, read the datas, then process the datas and send them using another USB port to the printer.

I'm using linux. I've found some javascript libs to use serial ports, but not USB.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the protocol the printer uses? Is it connected to a serial port (over USB) or parallel?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you don't want to modify the PC printer is currently connected to in any way or form. If thats the case, your main issue is going to be creating a box, with 2 USB clients, back to back, that would 'emulate' your printer on one side, and communicate to your second PC on the other. The second PC side is going to be easier, you'll probably be able to use libusb or alike to talk to both the printer and the printer emulator box and do whatever you want (although... libusb with javascript? never seen it done, but thats the least of your problems). Anyway, sorry to be the party pooper, but at least the way i currently understand what you are trying to do, this is simply impractical.

Remember, you can't simply plug in one USB host (the first PC) into another (your 'man in the middle' PC), and expect one of them to magically turn into a USB client, and emulate a printer.

PS: Start looking for some evaluation board with 2 USB clients and some MCU if you really wanna do this.
PPS: If someone knows some generic USB client to client box, that is fully configurable on at least one side (dev/interface descriptors, in/out endpoints numbers etc), i'll gladly stand corrected and would love to see more info on it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You're right, the middle PC can't magically emulate a printer. That's why I'd like to be able to read the raw datas, knowing the printer protocol. Readind your idea of generic USB client, I'll give a try with Windows as they're already plenty of generic drivers emulating serials from USB with that OS.

Comment: But it can't just magically turn into USB client either, nor emulate stuff like USB device descriptor, config descriptor, bulk endpoinds etc... in fact a stock PC doesn't have any hardware capable to run as USB client. All those things are required BEFORE you start actually running any real data through this setup.

Comment: Make sure you have some basic understanding on the topic of USB in general, whats "USB client", whats "USB host", how do they exchange data etc... i have a gut feeling you are going to find out thats a bit more complicated than what you've been thinking.